# relative and absolute imports with the same name causing "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute ..."

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

With the following code:

- `foo.py`:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  import package
  package.go()
  ```
- `package/__init__.py`:

  ```
  from __future__ import absolute_import
  import logging
  from .logging import config
  def go():
      config(level=logging.DEBUG)
      logging.getLogger().debug('this is a test')
  ```
- `package/logging.py`:

  ```
  from __future__ import absolute_import
  import logging
  def config(*args, **kwargs):
      return logging.basicConfig(*args, **kwargs)
  ```

I get the following error:

```
$ ./foo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./foo.py", line 3, in <module>
    package.go()
  File "/tmp/test/package/__init__.py", line 5, in go
    config(level=logging.DEBUG)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DEBUG'
```

It is as if the `from .logging import config` line is importing `.logging` as `logging` even though I don't want that.

If I swap the import lines in `package/__init__.py` so that it looks like this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .logging import config
import logging
def go():
    config(level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.getLogger().debug('this is a test')
```

then it works:

```
$ ./foo.py
DEBUG:root:this is a test
```

What's wrong with the original version?  Or is this a bug in Python 2.7.8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modules inside packages, once imported, are set as attributes on their parent package.

The moment you import `.logging`, it is added to the `package` namespace, e.g. in the `globals()` dictionary of `__init__` in the `package` directory.

By swapping the imports, you then replaced the `logging` global in the `__init__` module namespace with the top-level package again; first the sub-module was imported and added to the globals, then the `logging` package was imported, replacing global.

Demo:

```
$ mkdir package
$ cat > package/__init__.py << EOF
> from __future__ import absolute_import
> from .logging import foo
> print globals().keys()
> print logging
> import logging
> print globals().keys()
> print logging
> EOF
$ cat > package/logging.py << EOF
> foo = 'bar'
> print 'imported package.logging'
> EOF
$ python -c 'import package'
imported package.logging
['logging', '__builtins__', '__file__', 'absolute_import', '__package__', '__path__', '__name__', 'foo', '__doc__']
<module 'package.logging' from 'package/logging.pyc'>
['logging', '__builtins__', '__file__', 'absolute_import', '__package__', '__path__', '__name__', 'foo', '__doc__']
<module 'logging' from '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py'>
```

Right after importing `foo` from the `.logging` package, the `logging` global shows up. Importing the top-level `logging` package then rebinds the name again.

Comment: Do you know where the documentation describes this behavior?

Comment: @RichardHansen: looking for it now; package imports are a little underdocumented, to be honest.

Comment: @RichardHansen: unfortunately, I cannot at the moment find a good reference for you; I've added a demonstration of the issue, and for now you'll have to take my word for it that submodules are added to the globals of the parent package on import.

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation about this either.  :(